# Pass an object property through an URL

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, url

I have a list of objects defined like this.

```
var users = [{id:1,name:"Rudy",color:"Orange"},{id:2,name:"Sean",color:"Blue"},{id:2,name:"Rob",color:"Green"}]
```

I then make a table holding each object and their properties.
I want to be able to click on a row and open up a new page with all the properties in the corresponding object.

I have an html file called userinfo.html that looks like this:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
    {{user}}
        <td  ng-click="window.location.href = '#/userinfo#' + user.id" >{{user.id}}<td>
        <td  ng-click="window.location.href = '#/userinfo#' + user.id" >{{user.name}}<td>
        <td  ng-click="window.location.href = '#/userinfo#' + user.id" >{{user.color}}<td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to pass the user id through the URL. It will not let me do this no matter what I try. If I replace user.id with a string or integer it works fine.

Is there a reason it won't pass an object property. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thank You for any help!!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<td  ng-click="window.location.href = '#/userinfo#{{user.id}}'" >{{user.id}}<td>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this isn't working for me. It just reads the '{{user.id}}' as a string and takes me to userinfo#%7B%7Buser.id%7D%7D. Is there a way to append the user.id to the string in html?